# WPF Dynamic Icon Wierdness

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, icons, uri

I have an WPF application that has a dynamic icon.  Three emoji icons depending on apps state (Happy, Sad, Thinking). 
I have a Binding on the Icon, with a ValueConvertor doing the work and it works great.

Or so I thought.

- If I run the .exe directly from the directory, *it works **exactly** as planned*.
- If I run the app via a shortcut (on the desktop), it does not show
  any of the emoji, and just the default icon. (Yes the shortcut has
  Start in Field set correctly)

It is almost like the it cant find the resource; example: `icon = @"pack://application:,,,/Media/emojiSad.ico"` because it is being run from the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Is your icon's build action property set to 'Resource'?

Nomatter where you deploy your project from, it should almost always pick up your image if its Build Action is set to 'Resource'

Comment: Yes, they are set to resource.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to reference the icons?  I have always had no issue by setting them as embedded resources and referencing them as demonstrated at the following link.

[Images in WPF as embedded resources](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/349920/Images-in-WPF-as-embedded-resources)

Your converter could return a specific image as follows:

```
 return new Bitmap(@"images\emojiSad.ico");
```

Comment: `icon = @"pack://application:,,,./Media/emojiSunGlasses.ico";
var uri = new Uri(icon, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
return BitmapFrame.Create(Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream);`